# Symfony Process in Laravel outputs pgrep results on Mac but not on Linux Debian

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, grep, debian

Good Day Community Members,

I am using Symfony Process class inside Laravel 5.7, and attempting to use pgrep to get the process id(s) of PHP.

On Mac OsX it works as expected, the returned output I get is an array of the pids of PHP.

On the Debian server we use for production I do not get this output via the code, but if run the command pgrep php via SSH terminal, I do get the pids as expected. Replacing ['pgrep','php'] with ['ls'] when instantiating the new Process does return an array of files as expected.

```
$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process(['pgrep','php']);

try {
    $process->run();
}
catch (\Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException $e) {
     dump($e->getMessage()); //nothing
}
dump($process->isSuccessful()); //false
dump($process->getOutput()); //""
dump($process->getStatus()); //"terminated"
dump($process->getCommandLine()); //"'pgrep' 'php'"
dump($process->getExitCode()); // 1
```

I expected the output on Debian would be the pid(s) of PHP but the output is an empty string. On MacOsX the code works as expected, I get an array of pids.

Comment: According to [man pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) the exit status code should be 0 if the command ran and found PIDs and 1 if the command ran without finding any PIDs (etc). Not a solution but might be a place to start

Comment: Are you sure you entered valid php process name? What is your `pgrep php` output from command line? Looks like pgrep worked but didn't found process with name php. Another idea is not enough privileges of user that running php script

Comment: @IncOre the `pgrep php` outputs the process ids, and if I run `top` the process ids do correspond to the php processes listed there

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, I have updated the question to include results of call to `->getExitCode()` which does output 1

Comment: @dpgomersall Can you try pgrep on pure php? Something like `exec('pgrep php',  $output, $code )`

Comment: try comparing the command `whoami` from the shell and from the php code and check if the user executing it is the same. Then try running the pgrep command from the shell as the PHP user and see what you get e.g. `sudo -u <php user> pgrep php` and check if you get any results from the shell.

Comment: @apokryfos I get the same result running it in code and at terminal, its my username, as in `usr/home/username`

Comment: @IncOre running exec as instructed gives the following: `exec('pgrep php', $output, $code); 
    dump($output); // [] 
    dump($code); // 1`